# File isn't getting uploaded in a folder

Tags: php-7.1

Here is my code for file uploading in PHP. All the things seems at place but file is not getting added into the selected folder. The destination folder is stored in the same folder, where .php file is stored. Please help !!!

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image File to Upload:

    <p><input type="file" name="file"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't work simply like that, Saurabh. You need to specify a form action, where the action is the name of your php file on the server, which needs code to accept the form request, extract the file sent via the client and save it to the server.

Comment: Also there was a problem of Permission to write for the folder in Ubuntu. Now it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take the same example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

in your case you are missing attribute value of `action`

File :  upload.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

I have also share the link with you were you can use different type of validation on file uploads

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp